# Dompdf - Laravel no produce pdf con demasiadas páginas

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, dompdf

Mi problema radica en la cantidad de datos que deseo mostrar en el reporte pdf, ya que cantidades pequeñas de datos si los muestra pero en caso de cantidades gigantes no me los muestra, el reporte que deseo exportar debe de tener al menos unas 50 páginas pero éste no funciona, sí funciona con alrededor de 25 hojas y nada más.

**Código:**

```
$pdf = \App::make('dompdf.wrapper');
$view= \View::make('invoice::liquidation.entrega_mes.reporte', [
    'boletas' => $boletas,
    'deudas' => $deudas,
    'anio'=>$anio,
    'mes'=>$mes
])->render();
$pdf->loadHTML($view)->setPaper('A4', 'landscape');
return $pdf->stream('detalle_amortizacion_deuda.pdf');
```

**El error que me muestra:**

[image: Error]

Este mensaje me sale después de una larga carga.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tal vez se trate de que se supera el tiempo de espera. si fuera así intenta agregando esto al inicio de tu clase:

```
set_time_limit(0);
ini_set("memory_limit",-1);
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
```

Claro, que estos son límites exagerados, pero si funcionan, ya los puedes configurar a tu criterio y según tu necesidad.